# Select Tables that do not contain a certain column in Oracle 12c

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

Most  of the  tables in the DB have a certain column 'col_abc'.
How  can  I  find the tables  that  do not  contain this column 'col_abc'.

The  query

```
select  table_name
from  user_tab_columns
where  column_name not in ('COL_ABC')
```

does not  return expected result.

Thanks,
Amit

Comment: Are you only looking for such tables in your (the current user's) schema, or in the entire database, across all users (schemas)? Your attempt, using **`user`** `_tab_columns`, only looks at the tables owned by the current user.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way:

```
select table_name from user_tables
minus
select table_name from user_tab_columns
where column_name = 'ABC';
```

Comment: Very inefficient. `minus` will also sort the table names - which is not needed for this problem. Especially wasteful for the `user_tab_columns` table, which may have a very large number of rows (if there are many tables, and each table has, say, 15 columns on average). Set-theoretical operators, with the exception of `union all`, should only be used when there's no other way.

Comment: In my opinion this is a very good query. It's easy to read and maintain. If Oracle's optimizer has problems to run this efficiently, then they should work on that. (The optimizer should detect that this is nothing else than a `NOT IN` or `NOT EXISTS`, only differently expressed.) And as long as this doesn't become reeeeaaaal slow, who cares?

Comment: @mathguy Fighting talk! TBH I would normally only use minus in a clearly ad hoc query like this, not in production code - using it for it's brevity mainly. But I felt I should check your "very inefficient" claim. And it turns out not to be true, at least for 19.11.0.0.0 and this query. I find that `minus` runs about 5% faster than `not in`.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner -  By definition (SQL Standard, not even Oracle's choice), `MINUS` must also de-duplicate the result. Something like `MINUS ALL`, if it were implemented, would not require that. So `MINUS` is not the same as `NOT IN`. It is in this case, based on the **data**, not on logic. No optimizer can ever optimize based on data (which it doesn't know about, at the optimization step). So, no - `MINUS` can't be transformed into an anti-join.

Comment: @TonyAndrews - Wondering how you measured that. Obviously, for meaningful results you should run each query several times - and it should be on sufficient data. On my system, with very little data, I changed `user_*` to `dba_*` so the queries must churn through more tables and more columns; the `minus` query runs in 0.035 seconds on average, while the anti-join ('not in`) runs in 0.025 seconds. Still irrelevant; it would be good to see the comparison on a large production system (which I don't have access to).

Comment: @mathguy I was using ALL_TAB_COLUMNS (145 rows) and ALL_TABLES (2770 rows).  I used PL/SQL to run the queries 100 times each, fetching all the rows each time.  I think the timing differences are insignificant really.  I'm sure with different data results could be different!

Comment: @mathguy @ThorstenKettner the optimizer can optimize based on knowledge of the data model - e.g. if `table_name` were defined as a primary/unique key for `user_tables` (or rather the underlying base table) then it could know that `minus` and `not in` will be logically equivalent here.  Whether it actually does, I'm not sure.

Comment: @TonyAndrews - the time complexity of a "sort unique" operation (what Oracle uses to implement `minus`) is `O(n log n)` - so the performance difference will become greater on a higher volume of data. As to transforming `minus` to anti-join, note that `*_tables` are not actual tables, they are complex views. I don't see how one could optimize in the way you suggest. (Which is correct, if we were working on actual tables, and if what we select is the primary key column or columns in the first **table**.)

Comment: I see that Oracle comes to different execution plans and I also see that the plan for `MINUS` looks more costly. So Oracle failed to draw the necessary conclusion. `table_name` is indeed unique in `user_tables`, and though there are some views involved, Oracle could detect that uniqueness. It doesn't yet, but I am pretty sure that we will see the same execution plan for both queries in some future version.

Comment: @mathguy we are really talking about several things at once here: (1) the specific question, using user_tables and user_tab_columns: for this there is no penalty in using 'minus' regardless of how it works, for any realistically sized schema. (2) the performance of `minus` vs. `not in` in general (for any tables) - here I'd agree with you. (3) the optimizer's abilities in general - in general it may be able to optimize a `minus` as efficiently as a `not in`, based on constraints.  In some cases like this case it probably can't (but then it doesn't really matter in this case - see (1)).

Comment: We agree on everything, except possibly (1). There is no penalty in using `minus` unless the user is, say, an artificial user owned by an application (rather than an individual human user) - for example a PeopleSoft application - and the application owns a very large number of tables, many of which have a very large number of columns (resulting in very large `user_tab_columns`). The better argument may be that this query doesn't seem to need to be run more than perhaps a few times, so even if it takes "too long" it may be OK.

Answer (score 1):

The Below Query will give the expected results. Please modify <ur_Schema_name> as the required schema name

```
SELECT * FROM ALL_TABLES at
WHERE at.OWNER = <ur_Schema_name>
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM ALL_TAB_COLUMNS atc
                   WHERE atc.TABLE_NAME = at.TABLE_NAME
                    AND atc.OWNER =at.OWNER
                    AND atc.COLUMN_NAME='COL_ABC'
                    AND atc.OWNER=<ur_Schema_name>);
```

Comment: This is a good option. I prefer `NOT IN` and `MINUS` here for their brevity, but `NOT EXISTS` is a good choice nonetheless. `AND atc.OWNER=<ur_Schema_name>` is superfluous in this query of course.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use this solution using LEFT JOIN. It is a kind of NOT EXISTS clause.

```sql
select t.* 
from user_tables t
left join (
  select table_name
  from user_tab_columns
  where column_name = 'COL_ABC'
) tc
on (t.table_name = tc.table_name)
where tc.table_name is null
;
```

Comment: Why would this be "more efficient"? (It wouldn't; if this was the "more efficient" way to achieve the NOT EXISTS result, then Oracle would have used exactly this way to implement it. They are not idiots.)

Comment: I don't like anti joins. I consider `NOT IN`and `NOT EXISTS` (and `MINUS` sometimes) more readable. And I think that this is an important point; queries should be as readable as possible to be easy to understand and maintain. I know that very young DBMS often have teething problems with `IN` and `EXISTS`, because the developers focus a lot on joins first. In that case an anti join may be appropriate, if you run into severe performance issues otherwise. But apart from that situation, I don't know any good reason why to choose an anti join over its alternatives.

Comment: You are right. ANTI JOINS are less readable. But I only used to use them for performance issues. And in my own experiences, I found them more efficient.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner - You are using the term "anti join" incorrectly. By definition, "anti join" means the `NOT IN` and (equivalent) `NOT EXISTS` construct, not the left join construct used in this answer.

Comment: @mathguy: Thanks for pointing this out. I'm using the term as commonly used by SQL develepers (for whom a join is always a join :-) , but yes, in relational algebra where the term stems from the concept is not limited to the from clause, but is used to describe what you get with `NOT EXISTS` regardless the SQL syntax used.

Answer (score 1):

If you only need to look in the current user's schema, this is probably the simplest way to write the query:

```
select table_name
from   user_tables
where  table_name not in (
                           select table_name
                           from   user_tab_columns
                           where  column_name = 'COL_ABC'
                         )
;
```

This uses in a crucial way the fact that the column `table_name` in `user_tab_columns` is constrained `not null`.

If you need to look across all schemas, you need to use the `dba_` or `all_` dictionary views, and look for `(owner, table_name)` pairs instead of just `table_name`. Left as further exercise for you.